# MPI_Bcast Matrix Multiplication Setup

Tags: c++, mpi, matrix-multiplication

I am using MPI to multiply two matrices (2D arrays) in parallel, by dividing the rows evenly and dispersing them among the child processes. The master also works on a chunk of rows. I understand how to do this and successfully did it using MPI_Send/MPI_Recv but now I am trying to do it with MPI_Bcast and can't figure out when to Bcast and what exactly to send. When I output the finished matrix (C) at various points it seems like not all rows are being calculated/updated and I know it's likely because I am not correctly specifying the buffer.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int myid, nproc;
     int  Ibuffer[200];         // Integer buffer, use proper size and type
    double Dbuffer[2000];      // Double buffer, use proper size and type
    char Sbuffer[200];         // String Buffer
     int msg_len;
     int i, j, k;

    // initialize the MPI Environment and get the needed Data
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
     MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nproc);
     MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);

    // Get the name of processor
    MPI_Get_processor_name(Sbuffer, &msg_len);

    int RowA = 5,
    ColA = 2,
    RowB = ColA,
    ColB = 3,
    RowC = RowA,
    ColC = ColB;

    // Start clock
    double start_time = MPI_Wtime();

    // Initialize matrices
    double **matA = new double*[RowA];
    for (int i = 0; i < RowA; ++i)
        matA[i] = new double[ColA];

    double **matB = new double*[RowB];
    for (int i = 0; i < RowB; ++i)
        matB[i] = new double[ColB];

    double **matC = new double*[RowC];
    for (int i = 0; i < RowC; ++i)
        matC[i] = new double[ColC];



    for (int i = 0; i < RowA; i++)  // MatA
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ColA; j++)
        {
            matA[i][j] = 2;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < RowB; i++)  // MatB
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ColB; j++)
        {
            matB[i][j] = 2;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < RowC; i++)  // MatC
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ColC; j++)
        {
            matC[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }



    // All procs compute the chunk size, no need to send separate
    int chunk = RowA / nproc;
    int rest  = RowA % nproc;
    int my_start_row = myid * chunk;        // find my start row
    int my_end_row   = (myid + 1) * chunk;      // find my end row

    // assign rest ot last worker
    if (myid == nproc-1) my_end_row += rest;

    int Dcount = ColA * chunk;    // Data count for A to send to worker
    MPI_Status status;        // Status variable neede for the receive

    if (myid == 0)
    {       
        // Send the rows needed for workers (Don't know if I need this or not)
            //MPI_Bcast(matA, Dcount, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        // Then work on your own part
        for (int i= my_start_row; i < my_end_row; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j < ColB; j++)
            {
                for(int k=0; k < RowB; k++)
                {
                    matC[i][j] = matC[i][j] + (matA[i][k] * matB[k][j]);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int n=1; n<nproc; n++)
        {
            MPI_Bcast(matC, Dcount, MPI_DOUBLE, n, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            printf("\n ==++ Master Receive Result by Worker[%d], \n", n); 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // This is worker, receive the needed info and start working
        //MPI_Bcast(matA, Dcount, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        //printf("\n +++ Worker[%d], recived %d rows from Master \n", myid, myid*chunk);
        cout << "\n === Master sent rows " << myid * chunk << " through " << (myid+1) * chunk << " to process #" << myid << endl;

        // Do the work first 
        for (int i= my_start_row; i < my_end_row; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j < ColB; j++)
            {
                for(int k=0; k < RowB; k++)
                {
                    matC[i][j] = matC[i][j] + (matA[i][k] * matB[k][j]);
                }
            }
        }

        // Send the result to the Master
        MPI_Bcast(matC, Dcount, MPI_DOUBLE, myid, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("\n --- Worker[%d], Sent Result to Master \n", myid);

    }

    // End clock
    double end_time = MPI_Wtime();

    if (myid == 0) {
        cout << "\nParallel Exec time: " << end_time - start_time << endl;
    }


    MPI_Finalize();



    // Clean up and release the storage
    for (int i=0; i< RowA; i++) 
    {
        delete [] matA[i];
        matA[i] = NULL;
    }
    delete [] matA;
    matA = NULL;
    for (int i=0; i< RowA; i++) 
    {
        delete [] matC[i];
        matC[i] = NULL;
    }
    delete [] matC;
    matC = NULL;


}
```

If this question is too vague or troublesome I understand, I just wondered if I'm incorrectly understanding how and when to use Bcast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I don't make a mistake in my reading, this code generate the three same matrix at the beginning A, B and C for each processor, then compute the multiplication of A by B, but only for certain index. By this way, the result of this multiplication for a processor `rank` is

```
C(rank) = A(begin;end) * B
```

at the considered lines, and

```
C(rank) = 0
```

outside.

So the problem comes with the fact that `MPI_Bcast` doesn't add matrix, nor it concatene it, it's a broadcasting function, and send the buffer (here, the matrix C) from the root processor to all the others. So each processor, by doing the Bcast, overwrite the previous Bcast.

To concatene buffer, the function to use is `MPI_Gather`. But here, as the matrix is well-sized at the beginning, concatenation is not the good idea here.

Two options :

- Use a function that does the add operation and gathers data. You can see `MPI_Reduce` and `MPI_Allreduce` for that (but the operation that will be done is `x+(nbprocs-1)*0`, so it's not really useful to call such a function)
- Split A and C in sub-sized matrix, and then use `MPI_Gather` to reunite results.

Hope it will help!
Good luck